# What distributed process registries are available for Erlang?

Tags: erlang, distributed

I'd like to compile a reasonably complete list of distributed process registry libraries for Erlang.

Such libraries need to support basic operations like `register_name(Pid, Name)` and `whereis_name(Name)` (and ideally `registered_names/0`). Names shouldn't be restricted to atoms only, and these registration/lookup operations need to work reasonably reliably with multiple nodes participating in the registry (ignoring partitions for now).

So far I've come up with `global`, `gproc` and `nprocreg`. What others are available?

Comment: You nailed the obvious ones. I think many Erlang systems include their own variants in the code as well, but they are usually not applicable in a general setting.

Comment: I'd be happy to go looking at custom registries if the source is available. I've done a bunch of work on ejabberd already, so anything apart from that :)

Comment: I guess custom stuff on gen_leader (like gproc). In general register is a database.. so look for some dbs with strong consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that riak_core is such. I use its partition ring + consistent hashing to find the node, together with a local gproc instance to find the exact process. Thus I get very fine balance between fault tolerance, availability and speed.

Comment: I'll vote you up if you link to a github project :) But for my purposes, I'm not hugely interested in what _could_ be used to implement one, I'm interested in publicly available working implementations.

Comment: Sorry, it's a commercial project, belonging to my employer :(.
But regarding your requirement of "publicly available working implementation", I think you are quite out of luck (like I was), because I dare say, there is no good distributed process registry available. And don't get me wrong, I'm in no way saying that Ulf Wieger's work is crap! On the contrary, it's a huge contribution. But it's not distributed "enough" to be used in any real production system. At least not when you need speed and availability in a big cluster.

Answer (score 3):

[Locker](https://github.com/wooga/locker) is used in several projects at [wooga](http://www.wooga.com/) for registering processes.

[Riak PG](https://github.com/cmeiklejohn/riak_pg) is a "work in progress" alternative to pg2. The source code also serves as a nice example of how to use riak_core.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Riak PG:

It's mainly considered a "work in progress," because it was the result of some research that wasn't tested in production. Here's a link to the [Erlang Workshop 13 paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2505309).

If anyone has any questions regarding Core, or using PG in particular, I'd be happy to help out any way that I can.