# What is the idiomatic way of mapping IDs to processes in OTP/Erlang?

Tags: architecture, erlang, erlang-otp

I have a game server which hosts multiple instances of a game.  Players can enter an ID to join a currently running game.  In order to pair the client with the game instance they want, I have an ETS table which maps the game IDs to the PID of the Erlang process handling that particular game instance.  While this works, I don't really like having to use ETS, since it creates global data that isn't under the control of any one process.

What I want to know is: **Is there an idiomatic way in Erlang/OTP to map identifiers to processes?**  Is using ETS ok in this case, since the data is inherently global?  Or should I have one process which stores a dictionary of all the ID to process mappings?  I feel that is more Erlang style, but may not be as performant or concurrent.  I also came across [gproc](https://github.com/esl/gproc) while looking at other SO answers, which seems to be an improved process dictionary.  However, I was under the impression that using the process dictionary is frowned upon ([according to the erlang.org web page](http://www.erlang.org/course/advanced.html#dict)).

Comment: `gproc` (http://rustyklophaus.com/articles/20090916-GProcErlangGlobalProcessRegistry.html) is just fine. Its known to be more stable/improved compared to the built in Process Dictionary. You could also use `mnesia` ram tables but i think `ETS` is just fine as well.

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319553/what-distributed-process-registries-are-available-for-erlang

Answer (score 6):

`ETS tables` can be controlled by a given process/gen_server and their ownership can be transferred from process to process during times of trouble through the  [`ets:give_away/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#give_away-3)  or the  [`heir option`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#heir)  during the table creation. 
 Many game developers rely on something like `memcached` which does not differ (purposely) from `ETS`. However, `mnesia` is a very stable OTP Application and can handle much more concurrent updates compared to `ETS`. We have used mnesia in very busy applications and it has never gone down, unless the entire VM goes down due to other problems. Actually, most available systems built in erlang do depend on either `mnesia` or `ETS` for sharing state between redundant components so that as one fails over to another, in-memory data is available.
 [`gproc`](http://rustyklophaus.com/articles/20090916-GProcErlangGlobalProcessRegistry.html)  is a very handy tool especially for things like Gaming. This is because, a process depends on its own easily accessible data. No other process can look up another process's data. So , instead of keeping game state in `ETS`, you can as well use`gproc`. 
 Anyways, if u have time, you could try each option and do some load tests to see which one performs better.

Comment: Running `gproc` in global mode is also not recommended.

Comment: true, yet: with load testing , you will find that `gproc` is quite stable.

Comment: Not convinced, while load testing I ran into problems with `gen_leader` crashes having many globally registered processes in gproc.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but your answer doesn't really respond to the main question.

Comment: This answer gives the most idiomatic erlang response you'll ever hear: "try each option and ... see which one performs better". That aside, ETS tables (optionally wrapped in `gen_server`s) are fairly common. For a non-distributed cases, gproc works well too. See jlouis's [etorrent](https://github.com/jlouis/etorrent) project for an example of gproc use.

Comment: Mnesia is almost a distributed ETS table in the way that it works, so do check that one out.